# Use the name of a variable in the title of a plot

Tags: string, matlab, plot

I would like to use the name of a variable in the title of a plot. I tried this :

```
str = sprintf('Spectral analysis - WELCH - %d', X);
```

But this take the values of X, instead of X itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look here https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/251347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`inputname`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html).

You must create a function for this to work, since `inputname` returns the name of the input variables to a function. First create an [anonymous function](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) that takes one input `x`, and returns the name of said variable. Then call this function with the variable you want to use:

```
variable_name = @(x) inputname(1);
str = sprintf('Spectral analysis - WELCH - %s', variable_name(X));
```

Note, you must change `%d` to `%s`, since you want a string, and not a digit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am understanding the question wrong, you want the Variable Name to appear instead of the values in the variable? So something like this?

```
 VariableName = 1:5;
 structure = whos
 VarName = structure(1).name 
 CompleteVarName = genvarname(repmat({VarName}, 1, 6), 'VarName');

 str=sprintf('Spectral analysis - WELCH - %s ', CompleteVarName{2:6});

 >> str

 str =

 Spectral analysis - WELCH - CompleteVarName1 Spectral analysis - WELCH - CompleteVarName2 Spectral analysis ...
```